# Laravel validate sync input data with intermediate table values always fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-10

I'm trying to sync with additional data, like this:

```
$game->contestants()->sync([3 => ['budget' => 30.5], 7 => ['budget' => 25]])
```

Which works as expected, but I am trying to validate this input with the following rule:

1. The keys(model ids: 3 and 7) must exist in `contestants` table.
2. Each contestant must be the same `contestant_type` as what the `game` requires, let's say the **game's** `contestant_type` is `individual`, then the **contestant** should also be an **individual**.

So what I did was (I am using Form Request validation btw):

```
$rules['contestants.*'] = [
    Rule::exists('contestants', 'id')->where('contestant_type', $this->game->contestant_type),
];
```

But no matter how valid the contestant is, validation error always says:

> 1. The field contestants.3 is invalid.
> 2. The field contestants.7 is invalid.

But when I remove the `where` condition, validation succeeds, but I guess it's wrong, because when I try to input non existing contestant id, it still succeeds.

Any idea why is this? or where I went wrong?

Btw, this is how the request data looks in postman:

```
{
    "contestants": {
        "3": {"budget": 30.5},
        "7": {"budget": 25}
    }
}
```

Comment: You prob want to do it in 2 separate steps instead, first validate the contestants IDs, then go for the type.

Comment: that rule is checking the value not the key

Comment: @lagbox Is there a way to instruct the rule to check the key then?

Answer (score 0):

What your current code is doing is checking if contestants has an ID of "contestants.3" and "contestants.7".

You should extract the ID to the array and then validate that using your `Rule::exist` logic on `contestants.*.id`.